# How to Get json value by index in *ngFor in angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5

compontent.html

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select>
   <mat-option *ngFor="let i of jsonArray">{{i.name}}</mat-option>
 <mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

how to get the json key by index in angular like this{{i[0]}}

Answer (score 1):

in your ngFor loop just add a index definition like this :

```
*ngFor="let i of jsonArray; let i = index"
```

Comment: Oh no..  Actually I have json array for eg:   jsonArray=[{id:1,name:"ss"},{id:2,name:"dd"}] --- in mat-option element we will get this by *ngFor ="let aa of jsonArray" we get name value by {{aa.name}} instead of getting the value of name by calling key name called name but I need to get the key name by index .. like in typecript we can get Object.keys(jsonArray[0])[1]) so we get key name by index.. how this achieve it by ngFor..

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the json value by index in *ngFor using Pipe in angular 5

```
 @Pipe({name:keys})
 export class CustomPipe implements pipeTransform{
     let keys=[];
    transform(value){
         for(let key in value){
       keys.push(
            {
           id:Object.values((value[key]))[0],
           name:Object.values((value[key]))[1]
            });
    }
 }


 component.html
 <select>
 <option *ngFor="let i of jsonArray" [value]="i.id">
 {{i.name}}
 </option>
 </select>

component.ts
jsonArray=[{serialNo:1,project:"project1"},{serialNo:2,project:"project2"}]
```